What SATA drive failure is this exactly? “SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt }”
I have a some spare HDDs from hitachi that I keep for offline backup. It goes a few months offline and then get a ton of writes, then back to storage.
My drives always die after a year or so in this scenario, but this one died with some errors I've never seen.
Usually they just freeze and don't even mount. But this was more sneaky/dangerous.
It mounted fine. Nothing on kernel messages. I could even write a little to it, and then start the heavy backup and it immediately died.
I pulled it out (it is a hot-swap port and drive) and inserted it back in and tried to copy data again, and the logs are below.
How should I interpret any of this?
It's more a morbid curiosity than anything practical. And mostly because I want to know how to identify this earlier, since it fooled me for the first few writes.
[  904.050685] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  904.050761] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  944.382871] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  948.702800] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[  948.856105] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[  948.856128] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  948.856137] ata2: link online but 1 devices misclassified, retrying
[  950.789339] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  950.831289] ata2.00: ATA-8: ST32000542AS, CC34, max UDMA/133
[  950.831305] ata2.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
[  950.833416] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  950.833740] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST32000542AS     CC34 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  950.834452] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[  950.834479] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[  950.834487] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[  950.834520] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  950.834579] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[  950.909217]  sdf: sdf1
[  950.909548] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1091.660177] EXT4-fs (sdf1): recovery complete
[ 1091.678523] EXT4-fs (sdf1): mounted filesystem 60d2a9fd-f520-4999-857b-1368aee13764 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[ 1230.583205] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x7fffe00 SErr 0x30802 action 0xe frozen
[ 1230.583235] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[ 1230.583249] ata2: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt }
[ 1230.583268] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1230.583281] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:48:00:12:2f/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:01:01:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1230.583322] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1230.583335] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1230.583348] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:50:00:1c:2f/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
...
[ 1236.197872] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1236.197883] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1236.197896] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:c0:00:d2:32/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1236.197933] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1236.197946] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1236.197958] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:e8:00:5c:30/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1236.197996] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1236.198008] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1236.198020] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:f0:00:66:30/02:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 262144 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1236.198058] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1236.198077] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 1241.063371] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 1241.089525] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1241.089935] ata2: EH complete
[ 1243.063386] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x7ffff80 SErr 0x30802 action 0xe frozen
[ 1243.063422] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[ 1243.063436] ata2: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt }
[ 1243.063455] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1243.063469] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:38:00:a8:31/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1243.063510] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1243.063523] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1243.063536] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:40:00:b2:31/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
...
[ 1292.172594] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1292.172606] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 1292.172618] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:e0:00:b0:ab/0a:00:00:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq dma 1310720 ou
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 1292.172656] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1292.172675] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 1294.645804] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 1294.645827] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 1294.699119] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 1296.449086] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 1296.449109] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 1296.499285] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 1297.282471] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 1297.282494] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 1297.282506] ata2.00: disable device
[ 1299.115741] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 1299.115764] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[ 1299.115826] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[ 1299.115845] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#24 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1299.115853] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 1299.115861] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#24 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 ab 88 00 00 0a 00 00
[ 1299.115866] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 11241472 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 21 prio class 0
[ 1299.115916] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#25 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[ 1299.115923] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#25 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1299.115929] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#25 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 1299.115935] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#25 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 ab 92 00 00 0a 00 00
[ 1299.115940] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 11244032 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1299.115970] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#26 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[ 1299.115977] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#26 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1299.115983] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#26 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 1299.115989] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#26 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 ab 9c 00 00 0a 00 00
[ 1299.115994] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 11246592 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1299.116020] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[ 1299.116027] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#27 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1299.116033] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#27 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 1299.116039] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#27 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 ab a6 00 00 0a 00 00
[ 1299.116044] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 11249152 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1299.116070] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#28 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=7s
[ 1299.116077] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#28 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1299.116083] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#28 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[ 1299.116089] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#28 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 ab b0 00 00 0a 00 00
[ 1299.116094] I/O error, dev sdf, sector 11251712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1299.116134] ata2: EH complete
[ 1299.116169] ata2.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
[ 1299.116186] device offline error, dev sdf, sector 11254272 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1299.116248] device offline error, dev sdf, sector 11256832 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 8 prio class 0
[ 1299.116295] EXT4-fs warning (device sdf1): ext4_end_bio:342: I/O error 16 writing to inode 24643479 starting block 1407104)
[ 1299.116322] device offline error, dev sdf, sector 750811392 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4000 phys_seg 168 prio class 0
[ 1299.116372] device offline error, dev sdf, sector 750812736 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x0 phys_seg 88 prio class 0
[ 1299.116394] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404928
[ 1299.116407] device offline error, dev sdf, sector 750813440 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 168 prio class 0
[ 1299.116427] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404929
[ 1299.116449] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404930
[ 1299.116468] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404931
[ 1299.116486] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404932
[ 1299.116504] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404933
[ 1299.116521] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404934
[ 1299.116539] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404935
[ 1299.116557] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404936
[ 1299.116574] Buffer I/O error on device sdf1, logical block 1404937
[ 1299.116701] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 243828630, lost sync page write
[ 1299.116744] Aborting journal on device sdf1-8.
[ 1299.116766] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 243826688, lost sync page write
[ 1299.116787] JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for sdf1-8.
[ 1299.117239] EXT4-fs (sdf1): Delayed block allocation failed for inode 24643479 at logical offset 32768 with max blocks 2048 with error 30
[ 1299.117278] EXT4-fs (sdf1): This should not happen!! Data will be lost

[ 1299.117305] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1) in ext4_do_writepages:2737: Journal has aborted
[ 1299.121836] EXT4-fs error (device sdf1): ext4_journal_check_start:84: comm kworker/u65:8: Detected aborted journal
[ 1299.121916] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1299.121959] EXT4-fs (sdf1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[ 1299.121987] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[ 1299.122011] EXT4-fs (sdf1): I/O error while writing superblock
[ 1299.122041] EXT4-fs (sdf1): Remounting filesystem read-only
[ 1299.122059] EXT4-fs (sdf1): ext4_do_writepages: jbd2_start: 9223372036854775807 pages, ino 24643480; err -30
[ 1299.122354] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 1260, lost async page write
[ 1299.122383] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 1270, lost async page write
[ 1299.122384] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 98566301, lost async page write
[ 1299.122406] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 1271, lost async page write
[ 1299.122426] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 98574440, lost async page write
[ 1299.122439] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf1, logical block 1272, lost async page write


Update: After that documented failure above, I put in a (newer) Toshiba HDD and completed the Backup without any error or warning on the logs.
Later, I added another HDD (same model as the successful one) and got the following. After that, the rsync copy is chugging along… Never halted or showed any problem. It's been several minutes now.
[ 2661.932151] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x1f80 SErr 0xb0802 action 0xe frozen
[ 2661.932182] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[ 2661.932196] ata2: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt 10B8B }
[ 2661.932215] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932227] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:38:00:ce:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:01:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932267] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932279] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932291] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:40:00:d3:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932329] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932340] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932353] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:48:00:d8:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932392] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932404] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932416] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:50:00:dd:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932455] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932467] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932479] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:58:00:e2:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:03:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932518] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932530] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2661.932542] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:60:00:e7:4d/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:03:02:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2661.932581] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2661.932602] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 2665.445750] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2665.469300] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2665.469404] ata2: EH complete
[ 2665.932342] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x38000 SErr 0xb0802 action 0xe frozen
[ 2665.932377] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
[ 2665.932392] ata2: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt 10B8B }
[ 2665.932412] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2665.932425] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:78:80:83:5e/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:01:09:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2665.932467] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2665.932480] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2665.932493] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:80:80:88:5e/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2665.932532] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2665.932544] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
[ 2665.932556] ata2.00: cmd 61/00:88:80:8d:5e/05:00:18:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 655360 out
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
[ 2665.932594] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 2665.932614] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 2666.912377] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 2666.912409] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2667.046780] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 2667.354485] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 2667.509147] ata2: found unknown device (class 0)
[ 2667.509183] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 2667.601696] ata2: hard resetting link
[ 2670.519036] ata2: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[ 2670.545139] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/100
[ 2670.546967] ata2: EH complete


Is ata2 the controller connected to the problematic HDD? From the logs it looks a problem where the SATA link on ata2 goes down [ 1230.583235] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed just prior to the first failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED. Have you tried changing the SATA cables?

@ChesterGillon yes, ata2.00 is the drive. I have not tried to change cables yet, as changing HDD completed the offsite backup fine. I will try again with another HDD and if I have problems i will try the two "bad" hdd with new cables.

@ChesterGillon ok, another HDD worked, and yet another showed the same failure, but recovered(?) automatically... I will replace cables and try yet another full copy.

Most comments pointing to bad cable or interface were correct. It was a bad physical interface. Not exactly the cable, but I managed to isolate it on the "dumb" backplane (from the specs it should have been nothing more than a mechanical sata+power port, but there are some ICs there...)
Using the same cables but bypassing the backplane, and all previously failed drivers worked just fine!
So I will assume  SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt } means physical interface problems.
